# While loop looping on Separate Lines; Need to be on the Same Line

Tags: c++, while-loop

I need to my code to output the "fence posts" one after each other on the same line, but they are going on different lines. This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {  
    int posts;

    cout << "\nI can make a fence with from 2 to 18 posts.\n";
    cout << "How many posts would you like to have in your fence? ";

    cin >> posts ; 
    if ((posts > 1) && (posts < 19)) {
        while ((posts > 1) && (posts < 19)) {
            cout << "|---" ; 
            posts = posts - 1;
            cout << "|\n" ; 
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "\n\nSorry, no can do.\n";
    }
 }
```

And this is what it is outputting:

```
I can make a fence with from 2 to 18 posts.
How many posts would you like to have in your fence? 4   
|---|  
|---|  
|---|
```

Comment: `cout << "|\n" ; ` is creating a newline.  If you don't want any newlines then get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the inner loop with:

```
while (--posts)
    cout << "|---";
cout << "|\n";
```

Comment: That will do exactly what OP is doing.

Comment: Not exactly, but I have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Move the cout << "|\n" outside your while loop.

```
while ((posts > 1) && (posts < 19)) 

{
    cout << "|---" ; 
    (posts = posts - 1) ;
}

cout << "|\n" ; 

}
```